# BackgroundWorker to return a value from DAL during foreach loop

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker in my View which runs a sql query in my DAL.

On my view I also have a progress bar which keeps spinning so the user knows work is being done.

The SQL query receives as one of the conditions a `List<string>`, that I populate in one of the where conditions, so the code is something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_myHost))
        {
            conn.Open();

            foreach (string item in myList)
            {
                query = "select * from ( " +
                    "//big query with inner joins here" +
                    ") a " 

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                }
            }
```

So as you notice above, I run through all the items in my list querying them individually on the where clause (omitted above) and add the output, if any, to a datatable, which once the foreach is completed, will be returned to my view layer and become the datasource of a gridview.

It occurred to me that while I cannot query the server to tell me which % of the query is completed, maybe I could be able to provide the % completed of the foreach loop, which is some information to the user.

What I am trying to figure out is a way to:

Return to my view, the current iteration of the loop, which I could detected by simple adding a `int i` counter and increment it on each foreach, or maybe a `string item` in the beginning to inform what is being queried.

Thing is, I do not know how to return that value to my view as the codes execute. I considered C#4 Tuple, but it will not work because that is returned only once the method is completed and not during the `foreach` execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can raise an event or call a delegate from inside the loop.

Comment: What do you mean with _view_? Is this a WinForms app, a WPF one or something else entirely? Also, this code is part of the DoWork method of the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Its a Winforms App... shoud've tagged it as well. Sorry.

Comment: If it is just a matter of you having to know the stepNumber/stepName, why don't you just create a property with private getter in DAL which will be updated from your for loop and have your main thread read that every x number of sec and update the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a WinForms app the simplest method to communicate back to your application the state of affairs inside the BackgroundWorker is raising the ProgressChanged event calling the [ReportProgress method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx) and catch it where appropriate in your code.

This event is raised in the thread where your forms are (The UI Thread) so there is no problem with [trying to access UI components from a non UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c).

So for example your could write something like this

```
// this code is the DoWork event of the BackgroundWorker
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bkw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    .....
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_myHost))
    {
        conn.Open();
        int counter  = 1;
        int total = myList.Count;
        foreach (string item in myList)
        {
            .....

            WorkerItem item = new WorkerItem() { Counter = counter, Item = item};
            int progress = (100 * counter / total);
            bkw.ReportProgress(progress, item);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

public class WorkerItem
{
    public int Counter {get;set;}
    public string Item {get;set;}
    ... add other properties if you like .....
}
```

Then your winform code could start the BackgroundWorker and handle the ReportProgress event in this way

```
BackgroundWorker bkw = new BackgroundWorker();
bkw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bkw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bkw.ProgressChanged += bgw_ProgressChanged;
bkw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
bkw.RunWorkerAsync();
...

private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WorkerItem item = e.UserState as WorkerItem;
    ... update a progress bar, show the current item in a label etc...
    Console.WriteLine($"Completed: {e.ProgressPercentage}% {WorkerItem.Counter} {WorkerItem.Item}");
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting the first argument to ReportProgress is designed to represent percent complete (as an int); typically I see values calculate like `(100 * counter / total)` used for that argument.

Comment: Yes that's true, I was more interested to show the fact that you could pass an arbitrary object back to the caller. This will allow the caller code a lot more of possibilities than a simple progress percentage.

Comment: Yeah, when that is needed I usually just pass a percentage of 0 and include the information in the status object passed; I just figured it was worth mentioning since the property on the ProgressChangedEventArgs is named ProgressPercentage (as your second section of code shows.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way - pass a delegate into the method that is running on the background thread.

```
public void Run(Action<int> update) 
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_myHost))
    {
       conn.Open();

       int index = 0;

       foreach (string item in myList)
       {
          //Perform query

          //Notify the caller of progress
          update(index);

          index++
       }
    }
}
```

Note that the callback will be executed on the background thread.

## EDIT

I forgot about the ReportProgress method built into BackgroundWorker.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress(v=vs.110).aspx